# Tab on Website is "Not Clickable" Using Selenium w/ Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to use Selenium to click the tab for quarterly financials on this page:

http://www.msn.com/en-us/money/stockdetails/financials/fi-126.1.AAPL.NAS

When I run my code, it works some of the time, and sometime it tells me:

"Element is not clickable at point (897.7999877929688, 20.100006103515625). Other element would receive the click:

```
<span class="mectrlname mectrlsignin"></span>"
```

Here is the code I am running...

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import *
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.msn.com/en-us/money/stockdetails/financials/fi-126.1.AAPL.NAS')


wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 3)
qtrtab = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="financials-period-list"]/li[2]')))
qtrtab.click()
```

Does anyone know why sometimes I get the error message and other times it works just fine?  Should I be doing this differently?  Thanks!

Comment: Another element on the page is concealing the element you want to click. Catch the error and take a screenshot with `driver.save_screenshot`. That should help you debug the issue.

Comment: ah selenium race conditions...

Comment: I also don't understand why you're trying to click on the "Income Statement" tab when the url automatically directs you to the income statement tab. Isn't just going to the url sufficient.

Comment: The default view is annual, and I need to also see some quarterly data.  I looked up the term you used, "selenium race conditions," and found a recent article about it.  For anyone interested, here it is http://webtestingbasics.com/post/race-condition-testing-with-selenium

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a "frozen" header that covers the element you want to click when the cursor is moved to it. Just *maximize the browser window* to avoid this problem:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()
```